# Wordpress can't seem to handle tens of thousands of scheduled posts? Cron Breaks

Tags: cron, wp-cron

I have a website listing doctors in the us. I'm spreading out the posts over 2 years, but I have about 2.8 million doctors to list. Right now I'm adding the post automatically via a custom script, and selecting a random time between now and 2 years from now.

This seems to have broken my cron. There are about 40k scheduled posts, and the cron cell in the database was about 6mb when I exported the single cell for cron.

My cron is now broke, and it may be due to google xml sitemaps plugin. But that's a side effect I believe of the cron table getting too large.

What's the best way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please only helpful comments. I'm learning and ignorant in many areas as you can tell from my original question. I'm here to learn the best way to accomplish what I need. :)

Comment: I think I still don't comprehend. You're adding the *post* (singular) with a single doctor info by some script - is that correct? With random date - what for? And: why do you have as many as 40k scheduled posts? And scheduled for what, publishing?

Some greater detail about to give us the bigger image of what you're actually trying to do would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, each doctor has a page with their information. They are scheduled so that I have fresh content for 2 years, rather than coming out of the gate with a complete site.

I have 40k scheduled posts for the reason above, I don't want all posts to be live right away, I want them to be posted spread out over 2 years. Yes, scheduled to publish.

Is this enough information to help?

Comment: @DiH Pinging incase you didn't see the reply.

Comment: One way I would go about it, since you already do it the custom way, is to change their submissions dates to be in the future, so that they can all be published. So instead of scheduling each for a certain date, make its submission date the day on which that post should appear. The thing that would prevent them from being displayed before their due date would be just simple if statement within the loop in which your're querying for them, and which would only allow only for posts older than current date to be displayed.